# execute a method very time fragment appears

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to make an method executable everytime the fragment appears.  I have a MainActivity and a PagerAdapter and inside PagerAdapter, I have Fragments so my problem is that I placed a method inside my onCreate of Fragment but it's executing only once.  Maybe the onCreate of Activity and Fragment both have roles here.  After searching about a similar question I found this :

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        // Do your Work

    } else {
        // Do your Work
    }
}
```

But when I am putting my method here am getting a NullPointerException.  My method:

```
public void retrieveLocalStoredNotes() {
    notesArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    notesIDArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (NotesRealmClass note : NotesQueryRealm) {
        notesArray.add(note.getTitle());
        notesIDArray.add(note.getobjectId());
    }

    notesAdapter = new NotesAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(notesAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
}
```

Maybe am getting this error because I am initialising the variables in onCreate and setVisibleHint and it is running before onCreate.  How can I make this workable or is my approach not enough for that.

Comment: Call the method in `onResume()` method.

Comment: Consult this diagram on the fragment lifecycle to determine which callback method suits your purposes: http://baiduhix.blogspot.com/2015/08/android-how-to-do-findviewbyid-in.html. As @Prerak points out, it could be `onResume()`, or it could be `onStart`() or `onCreate()`

Comment: @PrerakSola Make that an answer.

Comment: @PrerakSola aeey thanks man ,  this is what i need

Comment: hey Allelopathy thanks man

Comment: viewpager is build in that way that you have in time min 3 active fragments/views inside it so neither of those three will call onResume, if you switch to third fragment, first will be called onPause and viewpager will initialise the forth fragment etc.

Comment: okay @ddog i'll keep this in mind and i have 3 fragments only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call your method in `onResume()` method.